# Flutter ios app not getting firebase notifications

Tags: flutter, push-notification

I have an application that I made with Flutter. Firebase test flight notifications are coming, but when I download from app store, firebase does not appear. does anyone know the solution

Comment: You have to describe all the things you HAVE done in order to get it working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.